# Why Is Inverse Quantization and Inverse Transform Taken Before Motion Estimation in H.264?

Tags: h.264, encoder, multimedia

Here is the block diagram of the pipeline for the H.264 encoder (*Fundamentals of Multimedia by Ze-Nian Li, Mark S. Drew and Jiangchuan Liu*).
[image: H.264 encoding block diagram]

The feedback loop is used for motion estimation, but why is it taken **after** the transform and quantization steps? Why introduce and overhead from the inverse functions?
[image: H.264 edited encoding block diagram]

I know there's likely a very good reason for it, and this might sound like a stupid question, but I'd appreciate any answer that nudges me in the right direction.

Thanks!

EDIT: MOVED [HERE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/163275/why-is-inverse-quantization-and-inverse-transform-taken-before-motion-estimation)

Comment: Motion estimation uses frames after inverse quantization and inverse transform because that's what the decoder will see (it has no reference frames), so the encoder, in order to avoid introducing in-loop desync, also uses "decoded" frames.

Comment: @Xosrov see also: [VCodex: 4x4 Transform and Quantization](https://www.vcodex.com/h264avc-4x4-transform-and-quantization/)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I did some reading myself as well and I'm starting to understand the pipeline a bit better. There's a LOT of prerequisites to know!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/163275/755

Comment: @nobody555 What you said is very accurate. I found this sentence in the book "H.264 and MPEG-4 Video Compression" by Iain E. G. Richardson:   



"It is necessary to use a decoded residual to reconstruct the macroblock in order to ensure that encoder and decoder use an identical reference frame for motion compensation."

I'll have to revisit this post again after I've finished chapter 3 of this book. It is very insightful.